# when should a web server do accept to create a new client, or reuse the same client?

Tags: events, server, language-agnostic, nonblocking

In a Webserver for basic static website non-blocking event-driven, I don't understand the mechanics I should implement for a "new client".
When a browser connects to my socket, I get the clientfd from accept and answer with a HTTP response, but when the browser is reloaded, should it create a new connection and answer, or should it reuse the same connection and just send the new response?

I use poll to handle multiple fds, but when I reload the page its the same connection (for me this makes sense) but then I open a new tab, and it's still the same connection (It only does accept once). I'm not finding any documentation on this, and I don't have a way to test with multiple client's if it reuses the same one every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reuse a connection from another client, new connections must always be accepted as new connections. It doesn't matter what kind of server application you're writing.

However, if the client passes the header `Connection: keep-alive` you should not close the connection once the response is finished, but keep the connection open for future requests from the **same** client.

Comment: Alright, I understand that part, I'm just blurry about what a web server considers a new connection. If my browser and Ip are the same, each tab is considered a new client? In the case I receive in the header the Connection: keep-alive

Comment: @ricardomart It's the browser's choice. You don't get any say in the matter.

Comment: @ricardomart  A new connection is one you accept from the passive listening socket.  An existing connection is one you haven't closed yet. What the client does is up to the client,  it it wants to  reuse a connection (with the `Connection: keep-alive` header) then it can do that. If the client want to create new connections for each request it can do that as well. It's not something you should bother with in your server. If there's a new connection you handle it as any new connection.

Comment: @ricardomart However, you *can* tell the browser that you don't allow it to reuse a connection, if you send `Connection: close` in the first response. In this case, the browser is forced to open a new connection for each request.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what both of you are saying @Some programmer dude and user253751 , I fixed that already, because i needed to know if i should close the clientfd after every connection or not, I just parsed the request and if is Connection: keep-alive I simply don't close it! Now I will try by sending Connection:close just to see if my web server can handle multiple request's without crashing. Do you guys know how to test a web server?

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand correctly,
but anyway, What i personally do is create a map of sockets, each socket is a client.
Every time a socket disconnects, it's being removed from that map... and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Whether to use a new connection is the browser's choice. You don't get much of a choice.

However, you can tell the browser that you don't allow it to reuse a connection, if you send `Connection: close` in the response. In this case, the browser is forced to open a new connection for the next request. This is the only control you have.

If you want to test several connections at the same time, you could open several different browsers, or you could use a different program, such as some HTTP load testing tool (there are many). You could also send it a web page with many images; browsers should try to download all the images using several connections at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

A web server doesn't create clients.  A web server *has* clients -- new clients trying to connect, and existing clients communicating on the sockets that it has already opened.

To handle new clients, a web server should pretty much be calling accept *all the time*,  unless it's already handling the maximum number of clients that it's configured to handle.

As soon as you get a new connection from accept, hand it off to other threads to process and call accept again.